# How many strongly connected components is there in this graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Consider the following graph. I can distinguish 4 strongly connected components, but they are 5.
Which one I missed? Also, can a node be shared in several components?

[image]

Comment: Look at whole middle row

Comment: @MBo good, however, it is the case of the middle column too! But they are all shared! Shouldn't be separated components?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5 components are:

- Top left node
- Top right node
- Bottom left node
- Bottom right node
- The rest of the nodes

What you thought of as components are not actually components, because they all can be expanded up to the 5th component from the list.

Notice that it is not possible to extend the listed components, because each of corner nodes is either unreachable from anywhere else (has only outgoing edges) or can't reach any other node (has only incoming edges). Therefore you can't add those corners to bigger component, and can't add anything to corner nodes to make them larger components.

By definition strongly connected components are largest possible (so that it's not possible to further extend them), but there's nothing about not having intersections with each other in definition. However it is easy to show that components defined that way can't have intersections.